# What is the real difference in terms of performance when you extract conditions from an if statement to improve readability?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to know how to calculate what is the real impact of changes like the following:

```
    if ((payload.transactions?.length > 0) &&
        (user.Type === UserType.Premium && user.status === UserStatus.Active)
    ) {
        doSomeStuf();
    }
```

```
    const hasTransactions = () => payload.transactions?.length > 0;
    const isActivePremium = () => { 
        return user.Type === UserType.Premium && user.status === UserStatus.Active; 
    }
    
    if (hasTransactions() && isActivePremium()) {
        doSomeStuf()
    }
```

where conditions are moved from an if statement to a function in order to improve the code readability

Comment: Unless you need to do those things millions of times per minute it will make no difference at all.

Comment: Function calling has significant overhead compared to just executing the code directly. As @Pointy said, the impact will depend on how many times you call the code.

Comment: You could break the condition up without making them into functions, `const hasTransactions = payload.transactions?.length > 0; `,  and then `if (hasTransactions &&...`   The function wrapping isn't adding anything here.

Comment: Use `performance.now()` to measure the difference in execution time

Comment: @Keith The function wrapping *does* help: `isActivePremium()` is not evaluated if `hasTransactions()` returns false. If you create two boolean variables, both expressions have to be evaluated all the time.

Comment: @Bergi  Yes, I understand short circuit boolean evaluation, but I'd be surprised if the nano seconds saved there would be more than a function expression, but I might be wrong.